# How to use distinctUnionOfObjects in Realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

I want to get all the distinct records for a column in **realm**

I know there is a method **distinctUnionOfObjects** in realm for this.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

While Realm does support most of the functionality of `NSPredicate`, sadly it does not support `@distinctUnionOfObjects` just yet. It's definitely on the roadmap, and there is an issue tracking it on [the Realm GitHub account](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103).

For future reference, there's a spreadsheet of the [`NSPredicate` syntax/keywords](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) that Realm supports on its website.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the URL. Saved my day

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. :)